# C++ - How do I properly unit-test a class or module?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm learning programming and C++ on my own, I'm working on a small project. I'm using Visual Studio. Recently, I started to write tests for my classes. A test for a class is just another hpp/cpp file with a `runTest()` method. All tests are run (with a `runAllTests()` method) when I run the program and open an error message if something is wrong.

Problem with this method, is that If I want to test a change I made to a class, every file that uses this class directly or indirectly needs to be rebuilt. For some classes this means nearly the whole project. My first thought was to make a separate project that only has the class what I want to test + all other files it depends on + the test-file. But for this I would need to keep the files in this test project synchronized with files in the main project, not to mention creating a new project for every class I want to test.

So how do I test classes (/units/modules) without having to create a separate project for each test? And how do I test a change to a class without having to rebuild nearly my whole main project? If its possible even.

Is there a difference with Test Driven Dev?

Comment: What's the problem with rebuilding the project? If too many files have to be rebuilt for a single change then you might have poor encapsulation of functionality into separate classes

Comment: If you want less rebuilding, split your program into smaller static libraries and create seperate test executables for each of these static libs. Another thing to learn is how to define interfaces (abstract baseclasses) and dependency injection. If you want to test a class you don't test it against real other classes in your project, you inject stubs/mocks with the same interfaces as the real classes which also reduces build dependencies.

Comment: If something has changes, it has to rebuild. Even if you have as many source files like the linux kernel and have to rebuild all... we talk about some minutes :-) I am a bit wondering that you write your own unit test setup. Have you ever take a look on free available ones like gtest?

Comment: With a CMAKE project I'd use targets - either the specific test I'm building or a more generic "tests" target that includes all tests. Certainly you could do something similar in VS? Make a custom build that only builds targets in "test" folder (and their dependencies)?

Comment: "Is there a difference with Test Driven Dev?" In a very short: You write the tests first and only implement until all tests are green. The idea is great but has its own drawbacks... bad written and incomplete tests result also in bad products :-)

Comment: Since you are just starting out, I recommend C++ [doctest](https://github.com/doctest/doctest) unit testing framework to get you started.  Once you're comfortable with that, if you need to move to a larger scale framework like Boost Test or Google Test it'll be easy.  (For my own projects, I'd even use doctest for larger projects.)  Catch2 is another good lightweight unit test framework, but I prefer doctest.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/writing-unit-tests-for-c-cpp?view=vs-2022

Comment: @Klaus Thank you! haven't looked at any since I'm new to the idea of unit testing. I will.